# Autofac Enumeration not working with multiple registrations of types or modules

Tags: c#, autofac, autofac-module

The [autofac documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html) states:

> when Autofac is injecting a constructor parameter of type `IEnumerable<ITask>` it will not look for a component that supplies `IEnumerable<ITask>`. Instead, the container will find all implementations of ITask and inject all of them.

But actually, it adds each registered type as many times as it has been registered. So, if you register a class twice as following:

```
builder.RegisterType<A>(); 
builder.RegisterType<A>();
```

Then you get **two items** in the enumeration!! Within a single module, it is not a problem, as you obviously take care to register only once your types. But if you have a shared module registered by multiple modules (typical diamond module dependency diagram), then you get as many items in the enumeration as the shared module has been registered by others...

Is it a bug?
Is there any way to force the enumeration to provide a single item for each implementation, as stated in the documentation, no more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to see *Autofac* as a kind of `Dictionary<IComponentRegistration>`. A *registration* can be tied to a type or a delegate or everything else with configuration behavior.

By registering twice the *Type* you will have two distinct `IComponentRegistration`, in your case the *registration* will be similar. If you look at the following difference you can see that you will have two different *registration* that use the same `Type` but with different configuration.

```
builder.RegisterType<A>().WithConstrusctorArgument("param1", "x"); 
builder.RegisterType<A>().WithConstrusctorArgument("param1", "y");
```

In this case resolving `IEnumerable<A>` will give you two different instance of `A` and it does make sense.

> Is there any way to force the enumeration to provide a single item for each implementation

I won't recommend doing that. It may be better to refactor your application not to allow this scenario, if you need that you will remove a lot of great things in *Autofac*.
If you have a `Type` that may be register in more than one module it may make sense to register this `Type` in the *main* module.

---

By the way, if you really want to do that, you will have to find a way to distinguish all registration of your container. Then you can override the default implementation for `IEnumerable<>` by implementing your own `IRegistrationSource`, the following example will give you only one registration per type.

```
class CustomEnumerableRegistrationSource : IRegistrationSource
{
    public Boolean IsAdapterForIndividualComponents
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration> RegistrationsFor(Service service, Func<Service, IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration>> registrationAccessor)
    {
        IServiceWithType typedService = service as IServiceWithType;

        if (typedService == null)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<IComponentRegistration>();
        }
        if (!(typedService.ServiceType.IsGenericType && typedService.ServiceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)))
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<IComponentRegistration>();
        }

        Type elementType = typedService.ServiceType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

        Service elementService = typedService.ChangeType(elementType);

        Type collectionType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(elementType);

        IComponentRegistration registration = RegistrationBuilder.ForDelegate(collectionType, (c, p) =>
        {
            IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration> registrations = c.ComponentRegistry.RegistrationsFor(elementService);

            IEnumerable<Object> elements = registrations.Select(cr => c.ResolveComponent(cr, p));

            // get distinct elements by type
            Array array = elements.GroupBy(o => o.GetType()).Select(o => o.First()).ToArray();

            Array array2 = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, array.Length);
            array.CopyTo(array2, 0);

            Object collection = Activator.CreateInstance(collectionType, new Object[] { array2 });

            return collection;
        }).As(service)
          .CreateRegistration();

        return new IComponentRegistration[] { registration };
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this :

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<A1>().As<IA>();
builder.RegisterType<A1>().As<IA>();
builder.RegisterType<A2>().As<IA>();

builder.RegisterSource(new CustomEnumerableRegistrationSource());

IContainer container = builder.Build();

IEnumerable<IA> services = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IA>>();
Console.WriteLine(services.Count());
```

This registration is a simplified version of the original [CollectionRegistrationSource](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/master/src/Autofac/Features/Collections/CollectionRegistrationSource.cs). Please have a look at the source code of the [CollectionRegistrationSource.cs](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/master/src/Autofac/Features/Collections/CollectionRegistrationSource.cs) for a more complete version of the registration.

Comment: Thank you! I understand the dilemma behind the scene. I was not aware that the registering of Types is not idempotent. And somehow you are right, it makes sense, if you want a unique registering behavior between Types and Instances. So, as a consequence, a module must be registered only once, even if multiple modules depend on it. *So the thumb rule: never register a module within another module! Keep a flat module model. Register them only in the outer routine, that creates the container*

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough explaination! I tried your `CustomerEnumerableRegistrationSource` with Autofac 4.9.4, but found it returns `0` elements with your example. Just wonder where the issue is.